# assign value to a variable rather than using if statement

Tags: r

Right now, I have dataset consisting of variables `Gbcode` and `ncnty`

```
> str(dt)
'data.frame':   840 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Gbcode                     : Factor w/ 28 levels "11","12","13",..: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 16 17 ...
 $ ncounty                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I want to do the following thing:

if a data record is with `Gbcode` equal to 11, then assign 20 to its `ncnty`

`Gbcode`             : 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21,  22,  23,  31,  32,  33
Corresponding `ncnty`: 20,  19, 198, 131, 112, 102,  60, 145,  22, 115,  95

I am wondering whether there is any better solution rather than write an `if` statement, which would be with many lines in this case, maybe less than 20 lines of code.

Comment: `dt$ncounty[dt$Gbcode=="11"] <- 20`

Comment: there are plenty of posts for this question
dt[dt$Gbcode == 11,"ncnty"]=20

Comment: @MattTyers Hi Matt, thanks! this is better than a if statement. However, actually I have 20 unique Gbcode, by using your code, I need write 20 lines of code. I am wondering whether this is anyway to write less than 20 lines of code in this case. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a `merge` operation as far as I can tell. Make a little lookup table with your `Gbcode`/`ncnty` data, and then merge it in. `lkup <- data.frame(Gbcode=c(11,12,13),ncnty=c(20,19,198))` then `merge(dt, lkup, by="Gbcodes", all.x=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `merge` operation as far as I can tell. Make a little lookup table with your `Gbcode`/`ncnty` data, and then `merge` it in.

```
# lookup table
lkup <- data.frame(Gbcode=c(11,12,13),ncnty=c(20,19,198))

#example data
dt <- data.frame(Gbcode=c(11,13,12,11,13,12,12))
dt
#  Gbcode
#1     11
#2     13
#3     12
#4     11
#5     13
#6     12
#7     12
```

Merge:

```
merge(dt, lkup, by="Gbcode", all.x=TRUE)
#  Gbcode ncnty
#1     11    20
#2     11    20
#3     12    19
#4     12    19
#5     12    19
#6     13   198
#7     13   198
```

It is sometimes preferable to use `match` for this sort of thing too:

```
dt$ncnty <- lkup$ncnty[match(dt$Gbcode,lkup$Gbcode)]
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be more elegant, but should do the trick.

```
Gbcodes <- as.character(c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33))
ncounties <- c(20, 19, 198, 131, 112, 102, 60, 145, 22, 115, 95)

for(i in 1:length(Gbcodes)) dt$ncounty[dt$Gbcode==Gbcodes[i]] <- dt$ncounties[i]
```